# How do I prove this sum of p-th powers identity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, induction, power-series

So, I was playing around with the sum of p-th powers and I managed to find the following identity:

$$
S_{p+1} \left(n\right)=n\;S_p \left(n\right)-\sum_{i=1}^n S_p \left(i-1\right)
$$

where

$$
S_p \left(n\right)=1^p +2^p +3^p +\ldotp \ldotp \ldotp +n^p
$$

and

$$
S_{p+1} \left(n\right)=1^{p+1} +2^{p+1} +3^{p+1} +\ldotp \ldotp \ldotp +n^{p+1}
$$
I've scripted a code in MATLAB to generate all formulas up to a certain power and this recurrence relation seems to produce the correct formulas for the sum of p-th powers starting with $ S_0 \left(n\right) = n $, so it seems to be true at least for the cases I tested.

Now, I'm not sure if such a recurrence relation already exists and has been proven, either way I am trying to find a way to prove or maybe disprove that recursive formula.

I was thinking about using induction to prove that recurrence relation:
With the base case, $ S_1 \left(n\right)$ knowing $ S_0 \left(n\right) = n $
$$
S_1 \left(n\right)=n{\;S}_0 \left(n\right)-\sum_{i=1}^n S_0 \left(i-1\right)
$$
$$
S_1 \left(n\right)=n\left(n\right)-\sum_{i=1}^n(i-1)
$$
$$
S_1 \left(n\right)=n^2 -\sum_{i=1}^n i+\sum_{i=1}^n 1=n^2 +n-\sum_{i=1}^n i=n\left(n+1\right)-S_1 \left(n\right)
$$
$$
{2S}_1 \left(n\right)=n\left(n+1\right)
$$
$$
S_1 \left(n\right)=\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}
$$

Now, I'm not quite sure how to approach the inductive step, can anyone guide me as to how to prove/disprove this recurrence?

Comment: Have you tried inducting on $n$ instead (for fixed $p$)?

Comment: I know how to prove fixed sum of p-th powers formulas if that's what you mean. What I don't know how to approach is proving that recurrence relation for the p-th power.

Comment: I meant that you can prove your recurrence relation by using induction on $n$ instead of $p$. There are clear relations between the $n$ and $n+1$ cases that make this easier to do. The induction step when inducting on $n$ will be to assume that $$S_{p+1} \left(n\right)=nS_p \left(n\right)-\sum_{i=1}^n S_p \left(i-1\right)$$ and show that $$S_{p+1} \left(n+1\right)=(n+1)S_p \left(n+1\right)-\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} S_p \left(i-1\right).$$ **Hint:** To help do this, you can make use of the fact that $S_k(n+1)=S_k(n)+(n+1)^k$ for any $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the original identity, its' just algebraic manipulation.

**Hint:** Show that

$$LHS =  \sum (n-k) \times (n-k)^p = \sum n \times (n-k)^p - \sum k (n-k)^p = RHS$$

---

In terms of how to prove that $S_1(n) = \frac{ n(n+1) } { 2}$, you can do so by (another) straightforward induction.